# Accessing Live Objects From Other Namespace Within Same Solution

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I understand that the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/740948/5853001) provided from a similar question compiles properly. However, I am not able to access the desired object I wanted to access at runtime. I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance object" from the code below:

```
namespace MyNamespace1 {

    public static class Program {

        public static User CurrentUser;

        public static void Main(string[] args) {

            CurrentUser = new User() { UserName = "someuser" };

            Console.WriteLine(CurrentUser.UserName);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace2 {

    public partial class ThisIsAForm : Form {

        private void justAButton_Click(object s, EventArgs e) {

            var uname = MyNamespace1.Program.CurrentUser.UserName;

            MessageBox.Show(uname);

        }
    }
}
```

I launch the console application MyNamespace1, thinking that it will instantiate "CurrentUser", which I believe it does.

Now, I launch the EXE file from MyNamespace2. However, upon click the justAButton object in it, I get the error telling me that the object I'm trying to access is not instantiated.

Thank you very much in advance. Sorry if I am missing something here, which probably is so stupid of me.

Comment: Your programs do not share the same memory. When you run the programs size by side they might use the same code, but they will not know about each other or be able to access to use the same memory.

Comment: Thank you, Romoku. So, I'm guessing there's no way from them to talk to each other, or is there? At any rate, thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The [.NET Framework Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces) recommends that we follow this namespace convention:

```
<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]
```

This will help with managing [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

There is also inter-process communication if the intent is to communicate from separate exe's.