# Working with methods and return values in classes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Maybe this is a very silly question but it's been a long time I worked with VS.

I'm trying to figure out how I can call a method/function from inside my program e.g. by pressing a button. But the method is written in `Class1.cs`. I show below what I'm trying but I know this is completely wrong:

```
namespace TestProject1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddingNumbers(3, 5);
            label1.Text = Result;
        }
    }
}
```

And in `Class1.cs` I have something like this:

```
namespace TestProject1
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static AddingNumbers(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 + num2;
        }
    }
}
```

If someone could help me understand this I would really appreciate. I don't need a full answer because then I won't learn anything.

I think it has to do with Public, Static, Void or something like this. I have tried to understand how this principle works by reading on MSDN but I don't grasp it for now.

Advice would be appreciated

Comment: Your `AddingNumbers` should look like `public static int AddingNumbers(int num1, int num2)` (note the return type `int`) and then in your button click function: `label1.Text = Class1.AddingNumbers(3, 5);`

Comment: After adjusting its return type like Rafalon suggested, you can call `AddingNumbers()` like this: `Class1.AddingNumbers(3, 5)`. This works because you declared it as `static` which means you do not have to instantiate an object for the class `Class1` to access the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed return type of AddingNumbers method it would be as follows

```
public static int AddingNumbers(int num1, int num2)
{
        return num1 + num2;
}
```

And in Form1 class you can called AddingNumbers(static method) by it's class name as follows

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var Result = Class1.AddingNumbers(3, 5);
        //As per your requirement you need to show it in label that's 
        //why used  ToString() method to convert from int to string
        label1.Text = Result.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing static method within a class still require you to call the full namespace. Therefore you should be calling it using `Class1.AddingNumbers(3, 5);`

And your static method need a return type `int`

Comment: Is this principle always the same? So if I call a Class `ClassCalculations.cs` I would write  `ClassCalculations.AddingNumbers(3, 5);` And instead of placing two numbers between the brackets I could use variables as long I use the right type of them?

Comment: Wait that is a totally different thing. The `.cs` file has nothing to do with a `class`. The `.cs` file if for project classification such as folder are. You can have a file called `client.cs` and have 200 `class` in that single file. If you create a class file called `ClassCalculations.cs` it will happen that it also create a class in that file called `ClassCalculation`. But for the question about principle yes it is always the same. In your case the `Class1` happened to be in the same namespace `TestProject1`. If it hadn't been you would have called using the full namespace and the class.

Comment: Where could I find more good info about this? I'm trying to grasp this subject but can't find the info I need. Appearantly people don't likek my question cause I could find the info somewhere else.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/740948/2748412) is an answer showing a very basic example of 2 different namespace calling. That and static are 2 different things